# How to send a variable from one router to another

Tags: node.js, express

Please,  I wand to send a variable from login.js to dashbaord.js using node.js.

This is my dashboard.js:

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Firebase = require('firebase');
var login = require('./login');
var user =  login.userId;

var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var login = require('./login');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/',  function(req, res, next) {
 console.log(user) //  this return an undefine 
  res.render("pages/dashboard");
});

module.exports = router;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reading up on the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) or through some [examples](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/examples/route-middleware/index.js) would be a good place to start.

Comment: please i cant get your example right. i declare userid as a global variable in login.js and want to use the userid in dashboard.js to retrieve data from the database. kindly help with a code example please. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The code in routes  only runs when the URL pattern is hit. So in the code below the value in user will be printed out every time the "/" gets hit but you only initialized user once.

```
router.get('/',  function(req, res, next) {
 console.log(user) //  this return an undefine 
  res.render("pages/dashboard");
});
```

The line for `var user =  login.userId;` is only set once when your main express app is booted up. That is why it's coming back as undefined. But you shouldn't be passing user information from module to module this way, thats what sessions are for.

**Sessions & UserIds**

If you want to get the userId you should be storing it in the users session or in a cookie then you can pull it out of the request object. Any data that is specific to a user you can retrieve from your database using their userId in the session. With express theres no built in support for sessions but you can npm install middleware that will take care of this for you so that you can then write.

```
router.get('/',  function(req, res, next) {
 console.log(req.session.userId)
  res.render("pages/dashboard");
});
```

**Environment Variables**

If you need to pass configuration settings around across multiple modules you can use

`process.env.${propertyName}` for example process.env.cat = "Henry". But that is for things you set once that are the same for all users.

Comment: @kehindehussein Its just an object. You would simply assign it a value after  a user has logged in and you've decided to create a session. Depending upon the session middleware you choose they will have documentation.